# Retrieving elements from the data of type datatable from asp.net webservice in android application

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, datatable

I  have a webservice in c# which returns the data in the form of datatable and I want to access the elements of the datatable dt which has 110 rows and 8 columns how can I retrieve each and every row value in my android appliation and display it in the table. Help me Please:

this is my webservice:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Webservice for generating category wise report")]
public DataTable getCategoryWiseReport(string district)
{
    var con = new SqlConnection("data source=(local);initial catalog=xxxx;integrated security=true");
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "ReportSummery";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@district", district);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ad.Fill(dt);

    //string ofc_code=dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    //string ofc_desg = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    //string ofc_name = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    //string dep_name = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
    //string total_comp = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    //string pending = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
    //string desposed = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
    //string interim = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
    //string defaulter = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i <= (dt.Rows.Count-1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        }
    }
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    //string s=ofc_code+","+ofc_desg+","+ofc_name+","+dep_name+","+total_comp+","+pending+","+desposed+","+interim+","+defaulter;
    //return s;

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using some ORM and map your data to array of objects?

Comment: no i dont. How to do that......

Comment: Try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650503/get-array-item-from-webservice-object-to-android/19653152#19653152

Comment: This is very broad question. Besides mapping your data to object (you can do this manually as well without any ORM), you should consider how to pass this data to client. Plain comma-separated string is not a good option, use some serialization instead - to JSON or XML, and on client side deserialize string to objects again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   StringBuilder JSON = new StringBuilder();
   JSON.append("{");
   JSON.append("\"Customers\":[");
   for (int i = 0; i <= (dt.Rows.Count-1); i++)
    {       
            //dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
            JSON.append("{");
            JSON.append("\"ofc_code\":\"" +dt.Rows[i].ofc_code.tostring() + "\", ");
            JSON.append("\"ofc_desg \":\"" + dt.Rows[i].ofc_desg.tostring() + "\" ");
            JSON.append("\"ofc_name \":\"" +dt.Rows[i].ofc_name.tostring() + "\", ");
            JSON.append("\"dep_name \":\"" + dt.Rows[i].dep_name.tostring() + "\" ");
            JSON.append("\"total_comp \":\"" +dt.Rows[i].total_comp.tostring() + "\", ");
            JSON.append("\"pending \":\"" + dt.Rows[i].pending.tostring() + "\" ");
            JSON.append("\"desposed \":\"" +dt.Rows[i].desposed.tostring() + "\", ");
            JSON.append("\"interim \":\"" + dt.Rows[i].interim.tostring() + "\" ");
            JSON.append("\"defaulter \":\"" + dt.Rows[i].defaulter.tostring() + "\" ");
            JSON.append("},");

    }

  if (JSON.ToString().EndsWith(","))
    JSON = JSON.Remove(JSON.Length - 1, 1);

  JSON.append("]}");
```

In Android part

```
      private static final String METHOD_NAME = "sayHello";// give the method name
      private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.android.com/";// give ur namespace
      private static final String URL = "http://175.157.229.119:8080/ wsdl";// provide URL
      private static final String SOAP_ACTION = METHOD_NAME+ NAMESPACE ;
      private static final String Customers= "Customers";                                      
      private static final String ofc_code= "ofc_code";
      private static final String ofc_desg = "ofc_desg ";
      private static final String ofc_name = "ofc_name ";
      private static final String dep_name = "dep_name ";
      private static final String total_comp = "total_comp ";
      private static final String pending = "pending ";
      private static final String desposed = "desposed ";
      private static final String interim = "interim ";
      private static final String defaulter = "defaulter ";
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

      HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
      ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
      final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
      final String JSON= response.toString();

       try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSON);

            // Getting JSON Array node
           JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Customers);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contactdata = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contactdata.put(ofc_code, c.getString(ofc_code));
                contactdata.put(ofc_desg , c.getString(ofc_desg));
                contactdata.put(ofc_name , c.getString(ofc_name));
                contactdata.put(dep_name , c.getString(dep_name));
                contactdata.put(total_comp , c.getString(total_comp));
                contactdata.put(pending , c.getString(pending));
                contactdata.put(desposed , c.getString(desposed));
                contactdata.put(interim, c.getString(interim));
                contactdata.put(defaulter , c.getString(defaulter ));
                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contactdata);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: hey bro i am tryin from two days to print this contact list but i cannot because the emulator freezes down and gives a stop message. or i am unable to retrieve the data from the contactList on to a textview or something.

Answer (score 0):

Download ksoap ( download ksoap2 jar file).
 1st you need to customize ur webservice, u need to make it as JSON string, following is the code u can use in android part

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "sayHello";// give the method name
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.android.com/";// give ur namespace
private static final String URL = "http://175.157.229.119:8080/ wsdl";// provide URL
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = METHOD_NAME+ NAMESPACE ;
private static final String ofc_code= "ofc_code";
private static final String ofc_desg = "ofc_desg ";
private static final String ofc_name = "ofc_name ";
private static final String dep_name = "dep_name ";
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

     HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
     final String str = response.toString();

        try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);

                // Getting JSON Array node
               JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(ofc_code);
                    String name = c.getString(ofc_desg );
                    String email = c.getString(ofc_name );
                    String address = c.getString(dep_name );

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: please can u help me by giving me the webservice that throws the data in the form of json.

Comment: just give me some time, i wil send full code including webservice

Comment: hv u changed, method name, namespace,nd url,if u done these changes thn put breakpoint nd check it, coz i dont hv Visual studio to chk it, if u stil get problem thn u can mail me @ jeetendra.gupta21@gmail.com